# What is the Taylor expansion of $W( \vec{n}+ \varepsilon \vec{\eta}, \nabla \vec{n} + \varepsilon \nabla \vec{\eta})$

Tags: taylor-expansion

What would the Taylor expansion of
$$W( \vec{n}+ \varepsilon \vec{\eta}, \nabla \vec{n} + \varepsilon \nabla \vec{\eta})$$
be about $\vec{n}$, to order $\varepsilon$? Where

$$\nabla \vec{\eta}=\frac{\partial\eta_i}{\partial x_j} \vec{e}_i \otimes \vec{e}_j$$And $\vec{\eta}=\vec{\eta}(\vec{x})$. Is this correct:

$$ W( \vec{n}+ \varepsilon \vec{\eta}, \nabla \vec{n} + \varepsilon \nabla \vec{\eta})
\approx W(\vec{n}, \nabla \vec{n}) + \varepsilon \eta_i \frac{\partial W}{\partial n_i}(\vec{n}, \nabla \vec{n}) +
\varepsilon (\nabla \vec{\eta})_{ij} \frac{\partial W}{\partial \nabla n_i}(\vec{n}, \nabla \vec{n})$$

where summation is implied.

Comment: Indeed, it is correct.

Comment: @RogelioMolina Oh excellent, thank you.